# Issue while passing bean in the conversation scope in spring webflow

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow, spring-webflow-2

I wanted to pass the one bean as a result to another state. I tried as follows but it is coming as null,

```
<action-state id="entryPoint">
        <evaluate expression="appController.getEntryPage(flowRequestContext)" result="conversationScope.studentBean"    />
        <transition to="studentEntryPage"></transition>         
</action-state>
```

From the above state I need to pass the result (conversationScope.studentBean) to another state. So I tried as follows,

```
<action-state id="changeMarks">
        <evaluate expression="appController.getChangeMarksPage(flowRequestContext , conversationScope.studentBean)" result="conversationScope.studentTypeBean"/>
        <transition to="changeMarksPage"></transition>         
</action-state>
```

The above code is not working as expected. can any one suggest me what's wrong with above code and suggest the right way.

Comment: As I understand these states belong to different flows. If so, how do you start another flow?

Comment: both are belongs to same flow

Comment: Could you correct the question then? There is a confusing phrase "_I wanted to pass the one bean as a result to another **flow**_"

Comment: upadted @Evgeny. Can you tell me how can I solve issue. I am getting BadlyFormattedFlowExecutionKeyException

Comment: I think `BadlyFormattedFlowExecutionKeyException` has nothing common with original issue. Check `execution` parameter in url. As for conversation scope issue, states look good and it's hard to say what goes wrong. Try to use `flowScope`

Comment: Are you sure that `appController.getEntryPage(flowRequestContext)` returns non null value?